# Asking the user what list to access from a different module

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-module

I have a few lists in a separate python file. What I want to do ask the user which list they would like to get access to, and then use that list in my main py file. I am getting an error, can't find attribute 'x', x being the input variable in which the list name is stored. Any help would be appreciated.

Code

```
import module_name 

lst = input('Which list?') 

a = module_name.lst //getting an attribute error, no lst in module_name
```

Comment: Please show us your code and where you get the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access lists by a string, you need to store the lists in a dictionary.

-- module_name.py

```
lst = { 
  'a': [1,2,3,4],
  'b': [5,6,7,8]
}
```

-- module_main.py

```
import module_name 

lstname = input('Which list?')  # a

xx = module_name.lst[lstname] 

print(xx)  # print selected list
```